# Function work after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

Anyboby help. Why function add class active `this.parents(".block-parent").find(".periods[data-period="+typelink+"]").addClass('active')` work after second click? need to be done after first click!
link for not right example http://jsfiddle.net/kngU8/

```
Page.contentSort = function() {
    var $eachblocks = $(".top10_month .periods");
    var $blockhead = $(".block-head__link");
    $blockhead.on("click", function(e){

        var $this = $(this);
        var typelink = $(".block-head__link.active").attr("data-date");
        e.preventDefault();
        $this.parents("ul").find("a").removeClass("active");
        this.className += " active";
        $this.parents(".block-parent").find(".periods").removeClass('active');
        $this.parents(".block-parent").find(".periods[data-period="+typelink+"]").addClass('active');
    });
};
```

Comment: you are binding click handler only once content is sorted (and rebind it each time after), you should not nesting handler inside function

Comment: please put your code to jsfiddle.

Comment: have you tried replace "on" by "live" ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kngU8/ "live" not work with my function

Answer (score 0):

because in first click you initialize the code so it works in second click! common logic
use $(function()); like this

```
$(function(){
    var $eachblocks = $(".top10_month .periods");
var $blockhead = $(".block-head__link");
$blockhead.on("click", function(e){

    var $this = $(this);
    var typelink = $(".block-head__link.active").attr("data-date");
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.parents("ul").find("a").removeClass("active");
    this.className += " active";
    $this.parents(".block-parent").find(".periods").removeClass('active');
    $this.parents(".block-parent").find(".periods[data-period="+typelink+"]").addClass('active');
});

});
```

try this this should work

Comment: this not help, because my function is initialized, example here http://jsfiddle.net/kngU8/

Comment: actually it is same but i didn't found the meaning of Page.contentSort and i thought you  are calling this function on click

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using this

```
var typelink = $(".block-head__link.active").attr("data-date")
```

to find the link you've just clicked on, and you haven't dealt with changing the classes yet so it's getting the previous element you gave the class active to.
The following will return the correct data-date value of the clicked element, not one you think it might be that's saught by class name.

```
var typelink = $(this).data("date");
// var typelink = $(this).attr("data-date"); // this isn't how data is used
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kngU8/7/